# Inner join query don't retrieve the most recent result

Tags: sql, sql-server, navision

I need to update my Item field "Vendor No." according to the most recent result of the field "Source No." of table "Item ledger Entry"

I tried to do a inner join between both tables (item and item ledger entry) but some of the results of this query was not the most recent.

So If i do this query with a specific case,

```
select top(1)
    [MR$Item].[No_], 
    [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_],
    [MR$Item].[Vendor No_], 
    [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Source No_], 
    [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type],
    [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Posting Date]
from [MR$Item]
    left outer join [MR$Item Ledger Entry] on [MR$Item].[No_] = [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_] 
where
    [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type] = 0
    and [MR$Item].[Vendor No_] <> [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Source No_]
    AND year([MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Posting Date])>=2018
    AND [MR$Item].[No_] = '3510100011' 
order by [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Posting Date] DESC
```

I get this results

```
No_         Item No_    Vendor No_  Source No_  Entry Type  Posting Date
3510100011  3510100011  505881497   172140064   0           2018-09-27 00:00:00.000
```

But doing this simple select, I can see that the last result is not right

```
   select top(1)
        [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_],
        [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Source No_], 
        [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type],
        [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Posting Date]
    from [MR$Item Ledger Entry]
    where
        [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry Type] = 0 AND 
        year([MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Posting Date]) >= 2018 AND
        [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_] = '3510100011' 
order by [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Posting Date] DESC
```

The results are

```
Item No_    Source No_  Entry Type  Posting Date
3510100011  508606977   0   2018-01-09 00:00:00.000
```

And the correct result is for the item "3510100011" I should have the number "508606977".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably the other conditions are filtering out the row you want.

Comment: Do you want to latest `Source No_` for all `Item No_` or just the one in your example?

Comment: @JamieLester I want all records, this is a example that my query is not getting the most recent

Comment: @AlvaroParra what??

Comment: The problem was here "and [MR$Item].[Vendor No_] <> [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Source No_]".. In all cases that they are the same, the most recent result is ignored. So now I try to do my query with select distinct but it is not filtering the duplicates

Answer (score -1):

Because in your query, you put :

```
AND [MR$Item Ledger Entry].[Item No_]='3510100011'
```

And, you can change your left join to inner join, because you are doing where on the table [MR$Item Ledger Entry]